# How can I modify the map of a Java IndexColorModel?

Tags: java, bufferedimage

I want to change one single color (yellow, to be somewhat specific) to another color in a BufferedImage which was loaded from a .GIF file.  I should be able to do it easily enough with getRGB and setRGB, but it would much more efficient if I could just change the color that the IndexColorModel's 'yellow' index is referring to.  Failing that, is it possible to create a new IndexColorModel which has the altered map?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
     BufferedImage bi = javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(new File("pathToGif"));
     
     if(bi.getColorModel() instanceof IndexColorModel) {
         IndexColorModel colorModel = (IndexColorModel)bi.getColorModel();
         int colorCount = colorModel.getMapSize();
         byte[] reds = new byte[colorCount];
         byte[] greens = new byte[colorCount];
         byte[] blues = new byte[colorCount];
         colorModel.getReds(reds);
         colorModel.getGreens(greens);
         colorModel.getBlues(blues);
         Color yellow = Color.YELLOW;
         Color blue = Color.BLUE;
         for(int i = 0; i < reds.length; i++) {
            Color newColor = new Color(reds[i]&0xff, greens[i]&0xff, blues[i]&0xff);
            if(newColor.equals(yellow)) {
                reds[i] = (byte)blue.getRed();
                greens[i] = (byte)blue.getGreen();
                blues[i] = (byte)blue.getBlue();
                break;
            }
         }
         
     }
```

This changed the yellow color to blue color, you can then use the changed color model to create a new BufferedImage and save it.

Comment: I get the idea; that should be effective for large images.  For small ones, probably getRGB/setRGB is efficient, since this way has to allocate a fixed number of arrays and Colors.

BTW - I think you have some typos in the code; the .getReds(greens) and .getReds(blues) don't look right.

Thanks!

Comment: @BruceFeist: I believe even for large index color images, this should still be a better way. You don't really need the Color object though. Just compare the red, green, and blue byte should be fine..Yes, I fixed the typo.

Comment: @BruceFeist Note that `setRGB` on an image with `IndexColorModel` will only be able to change a pixels color to another color already in the color map. While replacing a color in the `IndexColorModel` will replace all pixels of the that color with any color you like. The use cases are a little different I think.

Comment: @haraldK I understand that.  It's not a problem; exact color isn't critical with what I'm doing here.  My understanding is that Java uses an adequate but imperfect algorithm to find an approximation of the color requested.

Comment: @dragon66 I'm confused by your comment starting "I believe even for large index...".  I think we agree that your suggestion is best for those; it's for small ones that I think the getRGB/setRGB is probably more efficient, due to the overhead of allocating and releasing storage for arrays.  (It's less so since you pointed out that the Color objects aren't really needed.)

Comment: @BruceFeist:  sorry for the confusion, I mean even for small index color images, manipulating color map should be better. getRGB() and setRGB() are very slow methods to work with BufferedImage pixels, plus you will also have to check about return value of getRGB() with the color you want to substitute.